# Displaying Multiple records in a single form

Tags: vb.net

I have a table named `familydata` with Columns `[ID], [Name], [Photo]`.
I have added 5 records in that.
Now I want to show all the Photos from the every record on a form.
I have add 5 `picutreboxes` to my form but I don't know how to display all photos only. I don't want to use a `DataGrid`.
Please tell me how can I display all photo to my specific `pictureboxes`.

if you give code will be more helpful.. I am very new with vb.net

I have tried this but it is showing only one photo:

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection()
            cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;uid=sa;pwd=wintellect;database=master"
            cn.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "Select * from familydata where id=" + textbox1.text.trim()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                        dr.Read()
                        Dim data As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("Photo"), Byte())
                        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
            End If
            cn.Close()
```

ID is not a primary key. There are same ids for one family 
e.g: 
1 for one family and same for its members
2 for second family and same for its members

Comment: post your research efforts

Comment: Please narrow down your question. Do you know how to get the data from the database into your form?

Comment: I have added what I have tried..but it showing only one record. please help. Question is simple: I want to show multiple records in one form with different pictureboxes

Comment: Do you mind using the ListViewControl?

Comment: I just want to display photo to picture boxes with any method.... please explain

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the data you are representing is the same, you could opt for a UserControl, that contains access to the data you wish to represent.

So you could make a small class that represents the Family entity as such first:

```
Public Class Family
    Public Property ID As Integer

    Public Property Photo As System.IO.Stream

    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

And to represent this data, you can make a user control like this

```
Public Class FamilyDisplayControl
    Inherits UserControl

    Private tableControl As TableLayoutPanel
    Private familyPhoto As PictureBox
    Private familyName As Label

    Private _family As Family
    Public ReadOnly Property Family As Family
        Get
            Return _family
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        Me.Width = 128
        Me.Height = 96

        tableControl = New TableLayoutPanel()
        tableControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        familyPhoto = New PictureBox()
        familyPhoto.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
        If Not (Family.Photo Is Nothing) Then
            familyPhoto.Image = Image.FromStream(Family.Photo)
        End If
        tableControl.Controls.Add(familyPhoto, 0, 0)

        familyName = New Label()
        familyName.AutoSize = True
        familyName.Text = Family.Name
        tableControl.Controls.Add(familyName, 0, 1)

        Me.Controls.Add(tableControl)
        Me.ResumeLayout()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        Me._family = New Family() With {.ID = -1, .Name = String.Empty, .Photo = Nothing}
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(family As Family)
        Me._family = family
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

When you then read your data and create a new instance of the Family entity for each row, you could add the new controls to, for eg: a FlowLayoutPanel

This flow layout panel would then display the data based on your Family data, automatically sizes the content in your form and contains a reference to your family members in your database

This you could then do as such

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection()
cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;uid=sa;pwd=wintellect;database=master"
cn.Open()
Dim sql As String = "select * from familydata"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If dr.HasRows Then
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()
    While dr.Read()
        Dim data As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("Photo"), Byte())
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)
        Dim familyEntity as new Family With { .ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr("ID")), .Name = dr("Name").ToString(), .Photo = ms }
        flowLayoutPanel1.Add(new FamilyDisplayControl(familyEntity))
    End While
End If
cn.Close()
```

which would give you the full content of your family table displayed inside your flowlayoutpanel, with an Image and the name of the family

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataRepeater` control to do this.

For a start,

1. Add `DataRepeater` control to your form
2. Open the `Data Sources` window and a datasource. You can use a typed-dataset for this.
3. Drag fields from the dataset (Data Sources window) into the DataRepeater. Design it whatever way you want it to look like.

You can find several tutorials on this.

Here are a few of them:

1. https://youtu.be/Ox9w_LLyw38  (video tutorial)
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/08/12/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms.aspx

Once you start understanding how it works, you can then go about customizing it or do the data bindings etc. from code.